# Expect orWhere() to works with andWhere() instead where()

Tags: query-builder, typeorm

I have a query:

```
topics = await topicRepository.createQueryBuilder('topic')
                               .leftJoinAndSelect('topic.user', 'user', 'topic.userId = user.id')
                               .where('topic.categoryId = :id', {
                                       id: categoryId,
                                     })
                               .andWhere('topic.title like :search', { search: `%${searchKey}%`})
                               // It should take the first where
                               .orWhere('user.pseudo like :search', { search: `%${searchKey}%` })
                               .addOrderBy(filter === 'latest' ? 'topic.created_at' : 'topic.repliesCount', 'DESC')
                               .take(limit)
                               .skip(skip)
                               .getMany();
```

Generated SQL query is:

> SELECT DISTINCT `distinctAlias`.`topic_id` as \"ids_topic_id\", `distinctAlias`.`topic_created_at` FROM (SELECT `topic`.`id` AS `topic_id`, `topic`.`title` AS `topic_title`, `topic`.`content` AS `topic_content`, `topic`.`created_at` AS `topic_created_at`, `topic`.`views` AS `topic_views`, `topic`.`repliesCount` AS `topic_repliesCount`, `topic`.`categoryId` AS `topic_categoryId`, `topic`.`userId` AS `topic_userId`, `topic`.`surveyId` AS `topic_surveyId`, `user`.`id` AS `user_id`, `user`.`email` AS `user_email`, `user`.`pseudo` AS `user_pseudo`, `user`.`password` AS `user_password`, `user`.`rank` AS `user_rank`, `user`.`avatar` AS `user_avatar`, `user`.`createdAt` AS `user_createdAt`, `user`.`lastActivity` AS `user_lastActivity`, `user`.`signature` AS `user_signature`, `user`.`post_count` AS `user_post_count`, `user`.`updatedAt` AS `user_updatedAt` FROM `topic` `topic` LEFT JOIN `user` `user` ON `user`.`id`=`topic`.`userId` AND (topic.userId = `user`.`id`) WHERE topic.categoryId = '5' AND `topic`.`title` like '%admin%' OR topic.user.pseudo like '%admin%') `distinctAlias` ORDER BY `distinctAlias`.`topic_created_at` DESC, `topic_id` ASC LIMIT 20

The problem is here:

> WHERE topic.categoryId = '5' AND topic.title like '%admin%' OR topic.user.pseudo like '%admin%')

I expected :

> WHERE (topic.categoryId = '5' AND topic.title like '%admin%') OR (topic.categoryId = '5' AND topic.user.pseudo like '%admin%')

I want the **.orWhere** being OR from **.andWhere** instead **.where**

I don't find any documentation / issue about this use case.

Comment: Logical expression `(A and B) or (A and C)` can be simplified down to `A and (B or C)`, similar to how `xy + xz` is the same as `x(y + z)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The precedence of query conditions can be controlled by using the [Brackets](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/adding-where-expression) class:

```ts
topics = await topicRepository.createQueryBuilder('topic')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('topic.user', 'user', 'topic.userId = user.id')
    .where('topic.categoryId = :id', {
      id: categoryId,
    })
    .andWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
      qb.where('topic.title like :search', { search: `%${searchKey}%`})
      .orWhere('user.pseudo like :search', { search: `%${searchKey}%` });                                 
    }))
    .addOrderBy(filter === 'latest' ? 'topic.created_at' : 'topic.repliesCount', 'DESC')
    .take(limit)
    .skip(skip)
    .getMany();
```

(edit: added period to correct syntax)

Comment: Edit: I found the fix, I edited ur post please accept the edit ;) Ty Brackets was the solution, weird I never found something about it :(

Comment: The brackets are only mentioned in passing. Glad I could help.